# Tier 4 UK visa application

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, uk-citizens

I enquired about my visa application before this email was sent to me. I am worried because of the part where they asked me not to buy plane tickets yet. What could this mean? Is my applicant rejected? That is what the email looks like:

> Thank you for contacting UK Visas and Immigration International
>   Contact Centre. With regards to your enquiry about the status of your
>   application, I can confirm that we have made a decision on your
>   application. We cannot discuss the outcome of your application on-line
>   or by telephone. However the visa application centre will be in
>   contact with you in regards to collection or delivery of your
>   passport. We strongly recommend that you do not buy a non-refundable,
>   non-flexible ticket to the UK, until your visa application has been
>   approved and you have received your documents.

Regards,
Serge
UK Visas and Immigration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s post submission anxiety and also for students visas which are not covered here.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an advisory message, it means nothing as far as approval/rejection of your application goes. It is standard UKVI advice that applicants should not make travel bookings before getting their visa decision. Having proof of booked travel (flights, hotels etc) is not required as part of the application process.